# findOne with mongoskin and node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I'm trying (and failing miserably) to get a findOne function working on a mongodb. I followed this tutorial (http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/) and it works fine, but when I tried to get just a simple findOne going I have had such problems, can someone please help me out? I have searched every tutorial I can and I know you can't just use findone({_id: "idnumber"}), but I don't know what is wrong with mine:

```
router.get('/userlist/:id', function(req, res) {
db = req.db;
ObjectID = require('mongoskin').ObjectID;
var userToGet = req.params.id;
db.collection('userlist').findOne({_id: db.ObjectID.createFromHexString(userToGet)}, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result.username);
});
});
```

I get the error "Cannot call method 'createFromHexString' of undefined", where should I require my mongoskin.objectid?

My findall works perfectly:

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
db = req.db;
db.collection('userlist').find().toArray(function (err, items) {
    res.json(items);
});
});
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, when you do:

```
db.ObjectID.createFromHexString(userToGet)
```

, you should be doing:

```
ObjectID.createFromHexString(userToGet)
```

because you already declared the `ObjectID` variable when you did:

```
ObjectID = require('mongoskin').ObjectID;
```

Tip: never declare a variable without the `var` statement (unless it's REALLY necessary), because if you do that, it'll be in the global scope. Do this instead:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongoskin').ObjectID;
```

Comment: thank you, I left out the var by mistake but didn't know know i had to drop the db! Thanks again :)

Comment: Extra tip: use .jshint file and some jshint plugin for your editor. Then also add `'use strict';` line at the top of EVERY file you do. And it will point out all those `var` and similar issues :)